# PhoneGap error - "the page at 'file://' says"

Tags: cordova

Hi, I am creating an application using PhoneGap v1.0.0 rc2.
When I export and run it on my phone I get an alert style input box.

The first alert box is titled "the page at 'file://' says", with this : gap:["APP","overrideBackbutton","App0",true].
Hitting ok or cancel brings the next alert,
gap:["Device","getdeviceinfo","device1",true]

Hitting ok or cancel brings the next alert,

gap:["network status","getconnectioninfo","network status2",true].

I already placed the plugin.xml file in the folder res / xml, I do not know what is wrong!
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure in your main Java file you have loaded your landing page or the start up page when the app loads correctly eg: **super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");** where index.html is the main landing page.

Comment: Your Question is really vague I am not able to figure out what the problem is. You need to be more specific place your code. Explain more about the App and were you are facing problem.You can use debugging tools like http://jsconsole.com/remote-debugging.html , you can take a look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html